# How do we prove $\int_I\int_x^1\frac{1}{t}f(t)\text{ dt}\text{ dx}=\int_If(x)\text{ dx}$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be Borel-measurable and Lebesgue-integrable over $I:=(0,1)$. Further, let

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;g : I\to \mathbb{R}\;,\;\;\; \displaystyle x \mapsto\int_x^1\frac{1}{t}f(t)\text{ dt}$

I want to show that $g$ is integrable over $I$ and that it holds

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\displaystyle\int_Ig(x)\text{ dx}=\int_If(x)\text{ dx}$

*Proof*: $\;\;\;$ Please note that $g$ is well-defined, because $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable over $I$. So, by [Fubini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Fubini.27s_theorem_for_integrable_functions) $g$ is integrable and it holds:

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\displaystyle\int_Ig(x)\text{ dx}=\displaystyle\int_I\int_x^1\frac{1}{t}f(t)\text{ dt}\text{ dx}=\displaystyle\int_x^1 \int_I\frac{1}{t}f(t)\text{ dx}\text{ dt}=\displaystyle\int_x^1 \frac{1}{t}f(t)\text{ dt}=\cdots$

**How do we integrate $\int_x^1 \frac{1}{t}f(t)\text{ dt}?$**

Comment: Fubini. $ $ $ $

Comment: Tonelli :-). ${}{}{}$

Comment: So, you mean I just should change the order of integration?

Comment: @copper.hat For the integrability, Tonelli suffices yes, but for the equality of the two integrals one needs Fubini. If this matters... :-) (Dutifully upvoted answer.)

Comment: Prove is the verb, proof is the noun.

Comment: @Did - Thanks, I've updated my question. I've tried this before, but didn't know how to proceed with $\int_x^1\frac{1}{t}f(t)\text{ dt}$

Comment: @Did: The original question asked about integrability (and I wanted to give Tonelli some credit :-).

Comment: @copper.hat *Vai con Tonelli, vai...* :-) By the way, have you ever looked at [the picture of the guy on WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonida_Tonelli)? A tad frightening, no?

Comment: @Did: Too much integration as a young man, I think :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Fubini's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) says that since $f$ is integrable and for each $a\gt0$, $\frac1t$ is bounded on $[a,1]$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^1\int_x^1\frac1tf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_a^1\int_a^t\frac1tf(t)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_a^1\frac{t-a}tf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_a^1f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t-\int_a^1\frac atf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{align}
$$
Note that the region of integration is $\{(x,t):a\le x\le t\le1\}$. When changing the order of integration, the limits for each integral must be adjusted to represent this region.

Looking at $\frac atf(t)$ on $[a,1]$, we see that $\left|\frac atf(t)\right|\le\left|f(t)\right|$, and pointwise,
$$
\lim_{a\to0^+}\frac atf(t)=0
$$
thus, [Dominated convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) says that
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{a\to0^+}\int_a^1\int_x^1\frac1tf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{a\to0^+}\left(\int_a^1f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t-\int_a^1\frac atf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)\\
&=\int_0^1f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t-0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Why is $\int_a^1\int_x^1\frac{1}{t}f(t)\text{ dt}\text{ dx}=\int_a^1\int_a^t\frac{1}{t}f(t)\text{ dx}\text{ dt}$? I thought Fubini would lead to $\int_a^1\int_x^1\frac{1}{t}f(t)\text{ dt}\text{ dx}=int_x^1\int_a^1\frac{1}{t}f(t)\text{ dx}\text{ dt}$. What am I missing?

Comment: @oxbadfood: the region of integration is $\{(x,t):a\le x\le t\le1\}$. When we change the order of integration, we need to adjust the limits to represent this region.

Answer (score 3):

Let $h(x,t) = {1 \over t} |f(t)| 1_{[x,1)}(t)$. Note that $g(x) = \int_I h(x,t) dt$.

Since $h(x,t) \ge 0$ for $x,t \in I$, Tonelli gives  $\int h = \int (\int h(x,t) dt) dx = \int( \int h(x,t) dx) dt$.

We have $\int( \int h(x,t) dx) = |f(t)|$, and so $\int( \int h(x,t) dx) dt = \int |f| < \infty$. Hence $g$ is integrable.

Since $h$ is integrable, the function $\eta(x,t) = {1 \over t} f(t) 1_{[x,1)}(t)$ is integrable, and $g(x) = \int \eta(x,t) dt$. Applying Fubini (as in Did's comment above) gives
$\int h = \int g = \int f$.